# Execute a command as root in Cpanel plugin build with Perl

Tags: perl, cpanel

I am new to Perl.  I'm building a plugin for Cpanel to install SSL certificates when the user clicks an option.

I have to execute a command as root inside the Perl code.  How can I do this?

Comment: This doesn't look like a Per question, it is more related to system. Either you have to execute your script as root user, or you need to switch to run a system command from within your Perl code that switches to root and runs the install...

Comment: But my plugin will execute the command... i see a example in perl to execute bash command with `system(command, arg1, arg2` but i have to test a only sudo command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically you need to run a system command as `root` user from within a Perl script.

You can use the [system](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) built-in function with a `sudo` inside it. This will fork a new process where the command will be executed while the parent process waits, and then return the exit status of that command.

For example, this basic command switches to `root` and prints the current user :

```
perl -e 'system("sudo su -c whoami")'
```

Obiously, it outputs this on the standard output :

```
root
```

Notes :

- for this to work, you need you application user to be able to switch to `root`(without the need of typing a password) ; some could consider that a security breach (some attacker that would have taken over your application would be able to cause fatal damage to your system)
- the actual command to switch to the `root` user might vary depending on your OS ; the one I used in the example you is for RedHat
- I searched the CPAN for modules that provide the "switch to root" functionality and the only one I found is [Sudo](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sudo) ; I didn't try it, but it that was not updated since 2013 and has few issues pendings since 3 to 9 years